# how to set input date attributes using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, date, jquery-mobile

I am using `JQueryMobile` to create input date , such this:

```
<input 
                    name="mydate" 
                    id="mydate" 
                    type="date"
                    pickPageTheme="c"
                    data-role="datebox"
                    data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "highDates": ["2011-11-23"] }'>
```

but I don't want to set attributes values from `HTmL`, like this attribute `data-options`.
How can I set the attributes using `JQuery` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#mydate').datepicker('setDate', new Date('3/2/2011'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late but the correct answer is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mydate').trigger('datebox', {
        'method': 'set',
        'value': '3/2/2011'
    });
});
```

Related Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11290095/973155

Answer (score -1):

you can set data attributes values by using below code

```
$('#mydate').data("role") = "datebox";
$("#mydate").data("options").mode= "calbox";
$("#mydate").data("options").highDates= "2011-11-23";
```

[**refer this for more updates**](http://www.learningjquery.com/2011/09/using-jquerys-data-apis)

Comment: `$('div').data('options')` will be `undefined`.

Comment: I don't know what you've changed but your code is still very wrong.

Comment: op says that he want to set data attribute value through jQuery..it means op has defined tha data attributes but without any value...So i am just assigning the value to those attributes using jquery..