# How to programatically set a date in jquery mobile Datebox plugin 1.1.0

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I want to programmatically set date for the input with datebox control, For this i know i can use something like this

```
$(element).trigger('datebox', {'method':'set', 'value':'dateString'});
```

but this doesn't seem to update the control(i.e when i open the calendar, it is set to current date and not equal to the value in the input field)

EDIT:
based on JTsage's pointers i overwrote the default dateformat to mm/dd/yyyy, using sth like this.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.mobile.datebox.prototype.options.lang, {
    'en': {
        dateFormat: '%m/%d/%Y'

    }
});
jQuery.extend(jQuery.mobile.datebox.prototype.options, {
    useLang: 'en'
});
```

Then i tried setting the date using sth like this

```
$(element).trigger('datebox', {'method':'set', value:'07/02/2012'});
```

but this date is not appearing when i navigate to the page..Interestingly when i tried updating the date from firebug console(being on that page) it updated the field as well as datebox control.

I have no idea why this is happening..Need help, please respond JT

Comment: This is the correct method - but it will only work if 'dateString' is in the same format that DateBox is outputting.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i think that's the only thing i am missing. Will try that and update the same, again thanks for such a good plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So finally i fixed the issue, by doing this

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.mobile.datebox.prototype.options, {
    'overrideDateFormat': '%m-%d-%Y',
    'overrideHeaderFormat': '%m-%d-%Y'
});
```

setting the value of the input field explicitly

```
$(element).val('06-21-2012');
```

and then refreshing the datebox

```
$(element).trigger('datebox', {'method':'set', 'value':'06-21-2012'});
```

Comment: While this is fine, it would be nicer to be able to set the date by an actual Date object. There is a method for this: $(element).datebox('setTheDate', new Date()); Unfortunately, this does not update the widget.

Answer (score 0):

I found th solution, try this

```
 $(element).trigger('datebox', { 'method': 'doset' });
```